# How to restrict the range of elements of C++ STL vector?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

```
vector<int> l; 
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ 
   l.push_back(i); 
}
```

**I want the vector to only be able to store numbers from a specified range (or set).
How can that be done, in general?**

In particular, I want to restrict the vector to beonly be able to store single digits.

So, if I do a `l[9]++` (in this case `l[9]` is `9`), it should give me an error or warn me. (because `10` is not a single digit number). Similarly, `l[0]--` should warn me.

Is there a way to do this using C++ STL `vector`?

Comment: You seem confused here. The values of the elements inside the vector have nothing to do with the vector themselves. `l[9]++` could very well be equal to 2, for example, if `l[9]` was 1 before. The 0 and 9 in your example are just indices into an array, and have no relation to the values at those indices.

Comment: In the example code, `l[i]` is initialized with `i`, so I can understand the `l[9]++` syntax as a short hand for incrementing an element whose value is already `9`. It is not the clearest way of putting it as it leads to confusion though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An alternative solution would be to create your own datatype that provides this restrictions. As i read your question I think the restrictions do not really belong to the container itself but to the datatype you want to store. An example (start of) such an implementation can be as follows, possibly such a datatype is already provided in an existing library.

```
class Digit
{
private:
    unsigned int d;
public:
    Digit() : d(0) {}
    Digit(unsigned int d)
    {
        if(d > 10) throw std::overflow_error();
        else this->d=d; 
    }
    Digit& operator++() { if(d<9) d++; return *this; }
    ...
};
```

Comment: +1, substitute `raise` by `throw std::overflow_error()`... but the approach is good

Comment: Thanks for noticing, was mixing in some python there. I updated the code.

Comment: I'm positive someone like Sutter or Meyers wrote a nice `ranged_integer` class, but I cannot find it anywhere. In any case, a more generic version of this solution is of course possible. It would start with `template <typename T, T Min, T Max>` and you just plug in from there.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it with another class:

```
class RestrictedVector{
private:
    std::vector<int> things;
public:
// Other things
    bool push_back(int data){
        if(data >= 0 && data < 10){
            things.push_back(data);
            return true;
        }
        return false 
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not inhibit the use case that the question is about: incrementing a field already present. Even if it is a good step into providing that...